# Performance comparison of “patternnet” and “newff” for binary classification in MATLAB R2014a

Tags: performance, matlab, statistics, neural-network, classification

I have a binary classification problem for financial ratios and variables. When I use `newff` (with `trainlm` and `mse` and threshold of 0.5 for output) I have a high classification accuracy (5-fold cross validation – near 89-92%) but when I use `patternnet` (`trainscg` with `crossentropy`) my accuracy is 10% lower than `newff`. (I normalized data before insert it to network - `mapminmax` or `mapstd`)

When I use these models for out-sample data (for current year- created models designed based one previous year(s) data sets) I have better classification accuracies in `patternnet` with better sensitivity and specificity. For example I have these results in my problem:

**`Newff`:**

Accuracy: 92.8% sensitivity: 94.08% specificity: 91.62%

Out sample results: accuracy: 60% sensitivity: 48% and specificity: 65.57%

**`Patternnet`:**

Accuracy: 73.31% sensitivity: 69.85% specificity: 76.77%

Out sample results: accuracy: 70% sensitivity: 62.79% and specificity: 73.77%

*Why we have these differences between `newff` and `patternent`. Which model should I use?*

Thanks.